# Cant Conect to MySql in java with properties file

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, authentication, properties

I Encountered a really strange problem I don't know how to handle.

My app connect to MySQL DB to fetch data, until yesterday I had the connection details hard coded in the code , and everything worked fine.

**IE:**

```
connect = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://10.0.0.188:3306", "dudug", "qazqaz");
```

I have decided to make my application more modular , and have an option to change/set the connection details, and store it in a property file.

**Now when I use the following code:**

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

// setup the connection with the DB.

String user = props.getProperty("SqlUserName");
String pass = props.getProperty("SqlPassword");
String port = String.valueOf(props.getProperty("SqlPort"));
String addr = props.getProperty("SqlAddress");
connect =  DriverManager.getConnection("\"jdbc:mysql://" + addr + ":" + port + "\",\"" + user + "\",\"" + pass + "\"");
```

**, I get an error message like this :**

```
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for "jdbc:mysql://10.0.0.188:3306?user=dudug&password=qazqaz"
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
```

when debugging, both of the output connection strings are the same:

"jdbc:mysql://10.0.0.188:3306", "dudug", "qazqaz"

**Only when I use the modular string I get a problem.**

Anyone got any idea ?

Thnaks,

**Dave.**

**UPDATE:**

when is use this:

```
DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://" + props.getProperty("SqlAddress") + ":" + String.valueOf(props.getProperty("SqlPort")) 
+ "," + props.getProperty("SqlUserName") + "," + props.getProperty("SqlPassword"));
```

or this:

```
String user = props.getProperty("SqlUserName");
String pass = props.getProperty("SqlPassword");
String port = String.valueOf(props.getProperty("SqlPort"));
String addr = props.getProperty("SqlAddress");

connect =  DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://" + addr + ":" + port + "," + user + "," + pass);
```

its just gets stuck, posting no error message.

Comment: You need to have a mysql connector in your class path. Download it from http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/5.1.html

Comment: what does that mean ?

Comment: did you add the mysql connector library to your library files?

Comment: Why are you enclosing the URL with quotes?

Comment: What tool(eclipse, netbeans) that you used?

Comment: @Lunka , I have the MySQL-connector-java-5.1.33-bin.jar in my build path.

Comment: @feuerball that's the only way it works

Comment: Don't know if it matters, but your original attempt passes the username and password as separate parameters, but your refactored call doesn't (concats everything together).

Comment: @Davio it might be the problem, but I concat the String so it will keep the separation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, that you are trying to build the parameters list of the `getConnection()` method.

```
"\"jdbc:mysql://" + addr + ":" + port + "\",\"" + user + "\",\"" + pass + "\"");
```

evaluates to

```
"jdbc:mysql://10.0.0.188:3306","dudug","qazqaz"
```

This is **one** `String`, even if it looks like a normal parameters list. E.g. this gets called:

```
DriverManager.getConnection("\"jdbc:mysql://10.0.0.188:3306\",\"dudug\",\"quazquaz\"");
```

and **not**

```
DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://10.0.0.188:3306", "dudug", "qazqaz");
```

What you want to do is:

```
String url = "jdbc:mysql://" + addr + ":" + port;
DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
```

Answer (score 0):

Download the `mysql-connector-java.jar` and add it to your classpath.

Comment: it is already there: "MySQL-connector-java-5.1.33-bin.jar"  , I can connect to MySQL just not when using the data from the prop file !